# How to execute list of Action delegates with parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, action

How to execute list of Action delegates with parameters

```
  public static void CompareAll(List<Action<object,object>> compareDelegates)
    {
        List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();

      // The issue is in below line - how to pass parameters to the delegate
        compareDelegates.ForEach(del = (a,b) =>
        {
            try
            {
                del.Invoke(a,b);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

and calling the above function from below code

```
List<Action<object, object>> compareDelegates = new List<Action<object, object>>();

        compareDelegates.Add((a,b) => Compare(1,2));
        CompareAll(compareDelegates);
```

Comment: Why is it that your lower fragment does nothing with `a` & `b`? Is that intentional, a typo, something else?

Comment: i think you are confused about delegates. actually in `(a,b) => Compare(1,2)` two parameters of your delegate `a` and `b` does nothing. i think you should store parameters in list. not delegates which i think is only one delegate taking different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your delegates don't do anything with the input they're passed, you should use an empty `Action`. Change your code to:

```
public static void CompareAll(List<Action> compareDelegates)
{
    List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    compareDelegates.ForEach(del =>
    {
        try
        {
            del.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    });
}

// somewhere else...
List<Action> compareDelegates = new List<Action>();

compareDelegates.Add(() => Compare(1,2));
CompareAll(compareDelegates);
```

> EDIT: Since your question is puzzling, but doesn't really make sense in the way I solved above, here's another take

If you mean to have a list of `Action<object,object>` + 2 values, you should do that with a `Tuple` like this:

```
public static void CompareAll(
  List<Tuple<Action<Object,Object>,Object,Object>> compareDelegates)
{
    List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    compareDelegates.ForEach(tup =>
    {
        try
        {
            tup.Item1.Invoke(tup.Item2, tup.Item3);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    });
}

// somewhere else...
List<Tuple<Action<Object,Object>,Object,Object>> compareDelegates = 
  new List<Tuple<Action<Object,Object>,Object,Object>>();

compareDelegates.Add(Tuple.Create((a,b) => Compare(a,b), 1, 2));
CompareAll(compareDelegates);
```

Comment: His example delegate is `(a,b) => Compare(1,2)`, which does do things with the parameters.

Comment: Huh? What does it do with them?

Comment: ... oh snap. I assumed it was Compare(a, b) \o/ I still think it might be *meant* to be.

Comment: That's certainly what I would expect to be there, too. :)

Comment: I have no idea what it's meant to do... I tried asking in the comment... no reply, so here's my 2 cents of an answer. I can't see anything else to do with it

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
compareDelegates.ForEach(del = (a,b) =>
```

Your parameter is very strange. The type signature for `ForEach` in this case is `ForEach(Action<Action<object, object>>)`. Here's an example of how to use it.

```
object parameter1 = 2;
object parameter2 = 3;
compareDelegates.ForEach(a => a(parameter1, parameter2));
```

This calls every action in your list with `2` and `3`. Your example isn't very clear what that really means, though.